# Text and Images mess up when shrinking window

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. When I resize the window the text and images are messed up. How do I fix this?

HTML

```
<img src="images\titles_03.jpg" class="tt1" > 
<img src="images\titles_05.jpg" class="tt2" > 
<img src="images\titles_07.jpg" class="tt3" >
```

CSS

```
 .tt1 { 
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 759px;
  top: 200px;
  }


 .tt2 { 
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 200px;
  }

 .tt3 { 
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: -759px;
  top: 200px;
  }
```

It's not the full code, but this is the part that is messed up.

Comment: You're using absolute positioning here, what exactly do you expect when resizing?

Comment: Can you tell how to fix it?

Comment: It is the only way i found because if there is no position:absolute i cant center it and thats why i used positioning

Comment: You should use `display: flex` instead.

Comment: Also, URLs use forward slashes.

Comment: We cannot view your code here, atleast add a screenshot or working Fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Your image sizes are most likely set to the pixel size of the image. Try using a percentage to set the size of the images.

```
length:15%;
width:10%;
```

Comment: It works for images, how can i make it work for text?

Comment: @ValioRaltchev don't use absolute positioning

Comment: if i dont the image dissappears

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things, use floats and percentages for the sizes and placements.

```css
img {
    margin-top: 200px; /* use margin to position from the top */
    float: left; /* Float to align the images to the left */
    width: 33%; /* 3 images / 100% = 33.3% */
    max-width: 100%; /* use max width to constrain proportions */
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" class="tt1" > 
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2" class="tt2" > 
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3" class="tt3" >
```

Comment: as i said this is not the full code, its really big and messy and there are lots of pictures on different places, aloso text, and all must be in the center

Comment: Then it sounds like there is no quick fix for you, you'll need to format the page again using relative positioning for it to be responsive.

Comment: how can relative positioning help me?

Comment: Relative positioned items are positioned relatively to the document. Absolute positioned elements are forced and won't work for a responsive site. https://codemyviews.com/blog/the-lowdown-on-absolute-vs-relative-positioning

Comment: Then it's no use to make the site, i dont have that much time to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to use a resizeble sites, using like images and font-size depending on screen size you have 2 options :

1 - You use percentage on positioning like - height:30% ; width:30%;

2 - Media queries - A media query consists of a media type and at least one expression that limits the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as width, height, and color.